# PolicySimulator for ec2:AttachVolume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk, aws-policies

I am trying to validate action `ec2:AttachVolume` using policy simulator sdk java API.
my policy looks as follows

```
{
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVolume"
            ]
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVolume"
            ]
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
            ]
        }
```

How can i validate it using policy simulator API as I need to provide both the resource i.e. instance and volume?

Answer (score 0):

With this policy the [simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) works fine for me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DetachVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "ec2:SourceInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/i-1234567890"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]